# How to edit .csproj file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, csproj

When I am compiling my .csproj file using .NET Framework 4.0 MSBUILD.EXE file, I am getting an error: "lable01" not found in the current context of "website01.csproj".

Actually, I need to add every ASP.NET page with its code-behind file's reference. I've done it, it's working fine, but the above error is pending.

I hope it means that I need to add form name "LABLE01" in that .csproj file, but I do not know the syntax. Anybody please do provide me with the syntax to add form name in .csproj file.

Answer (score 537, accepted):

> The `CSPROJ` file, saved in XML format, stores all the references for
> your project including your compilation options. There is also an SLN
> file, which stores information about projects that make up your
> solution.

<sup>*(Source: [Microsoft forums, Narayanan Dayalan](https://social.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/e8e9a55e-6e43-4c4d-93f6-5a89157b12f1/what-is-csproj-file))*</sup>

Then paraphrasing the [MS Docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20101224005054/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171487.aspx), if you are using Visual Studio and you have the need to view or edit your `CSPROJ` file, while in Visual Studio, you can do so by following these simple steps:

1. Right-click on your project in solution explorer and select Unload Project
2. Right-click on the project (tagged as unavailable in solution explorer) and click "Edit yourproj.csproj". This will open up your CSPROJ file for editing.
3. After making the changes you want, save, and close the file. Right-click again on the node and choose Reload Project when done.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2022 you simply click 'Edit Project File'

Comment: Note you must unload project first by right clicking on the project node in the solution explorer and selecting "Unload project", before you can edit it like @bongoSLAP said.

Answer (score 50):

Since the question is not directly mentioning Visual Studio, I will post how to do this in JetBrains Rider.

**From context menu**

1. Right-click your project
2. Go to edit
3. Edit '{project-name.csproj}'

[image]

**With shortcut**

1. Select project
2. Press <kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: Or simply use the usual ["Go To File"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_File.html) shortcut and type `csproj`.

Answer (score 23):

You can right click the project file, select "Unload project" then you can open the file directly for editing by selecting "Edit project name.csproj".

You will have to load the project back after you have saved your changes in order for it to compile.

See [How to: Unload and Reload Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt479x1t.aspx) on MSDN, as well as the linked [How to: Edit Project Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms171487(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

---

Since project files are XML files, you can also simply edit them using any text editor that supports Unicode (notepad, notepad++ etc...)

**However**, I would be very reluctant to edit these files by hand - use the Solution explorer for this if at all possible. If you have errors and you know how to fix them manually, go ahead, but be aware that you can completely ruin the project file if you don't know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Well, hope to manually add the label name in .csproj file??? i mean the syntax....

Comment: @Karthik Malla - If you look at other classes in the project file, you will see the syntax.

Comment: yeah... but i cannot find anything related to forms in .csproj files but in my compilation with MSBUILD.EXE shows me an error with code CS0103

Comment: @Karthik Malla - You should also be getting a filename and line number with that error.

Comment: yes...! but i can do nothing.... The ASP.NET page with its C# code is working fine with a VS compiler but when I use msbuild.exe to compile a .csproj file then I am getting an error that I don't have a reference for that form in .csproj file. So, I need syntax to add the form name in that .csproj file.

Comment: Visual studio makes a complete mess of project files, adding much duplicate information. It makes it nightmare to maintain hundreds of them on a large project. Thus I never ever modify them in visual studio anymore. Becuase if you do, VS will take your new setting and multiply it by the number of configurations and platforms you are targeting. And that can get large.

Answer (score 17):

Here is my option to **Edit** the project file without the need to **Unload** the project:

1. Open Solution Explorer and switch to folder view:
   [image]
2. Navigate to the Project which you want to edit inside the Solution folders and right-click on it.
3. Choose `Open` from the Context Menu.
   [image]

That is it!

You will see the `*.csproj` file opened inside Visual Studio Editor.
After, you can switch back to a Solution/Project view (see step 1).

[image]

---

**Update:**

Starting from Visual Studio 2019 (v. 16), you can edit the `*.csproj` file by double-clicking on the Project. Make sure that you have the option turned On from the settings.

[image]

### Or

You have to click on the "Switch between solutions and available views" icon (updated since VS 19+).

[image]

Then click on the "Folder View (..."

[image]

And continue from 2nd step (above).

*Note: if you want to switch back, you have to click on "*.sln"*

Comment: Looks like your update suggestion is not available for vs2022.

Comment: @BashirMomen, thank you! It is actually there. Please see the 2nd update from the post.

Comment: Thanks, Arsen, I meant "Starting from Visual Studio 2019 (v. 16)..." is not available, still interested in it because it is built in vs fn. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I missed checking it for VS 19 cause now I'm switched to VS 22.  Updated ;)

Answer (score 14):

There is an easier way so you don't have to unload the project. Just install this tool called **EditProj** in Visual Studio:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EdMunoz.EditProj

Then right click edit you will have a new menu item Edit Project File :)
[image]

Comment: Best option, but only works with Visual Studio 2012, 2013, 2015

Comment: See the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Heku.EditProject2022 for newer versions.

Answer (score 14):

in vs 2019 Version 16.8.2
right click on you project name
and click on "Edit Project File" [image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a Visual Studio Extension... great tip but not OOTB.

Answer (score 3):

For JetBrains Rider:

First Option

1. Unload Project
2. Double click the unloaded project

Second option:

1. Click on the project
2. Press F4

That's it!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, most efficient way with out stuffing your proj file is.

1. right click the file.
2. goto properties
3. where Build Action option is set it to NONE.
4. Do a build (yes you may get build error if you do even better)
5. go back to properties of that file
6. set Build Action option is set it back to Compile.
7. rebuild.
8. Congratulate your self for being smarter than everyone else and not ****ing you project. For me this exercise took under 10 seconds. Where as manually trying to input the compile... line into the csproj not only can render your project unusable but it is also impossible to maintain on large scale application. Better to keep source version control software to do the updates. If you need to cross merge branches then doing the above is amazing :).

Answer (score 2):

You can also open the .csproj by double-clicking on the project file. So no need to right click and select edit project file. Just double click and that is it.

Comment: This is true for .net 6, but not for .net 4 projects.

Comment: Thanks @Chrigl. I didnt test with older .NET versions so can't say.

Answer (score 1):

To open the .csproj file:

- open the solution explorer
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrUXp.png)
- Click on the Edit Project File option
  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWxmb.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is a built-in option .Net core and .Net standard projects

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio-version: 8.1.5,

1. Right click on the project folder.
2. Click "Tools", then "Edit File".

Comment: Hi @Asem. You're not answering the question, as the user needs help with the syntax. Please take a look at [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @GaboBrandX Most of the answers are answering the question "how to edit .csproj file?" , including me. I came across the problem, and checked the provided answers, but none of the answers were helpful. So, I provided an answer for the last updated version.

Comment: Only your answer was provided to me to be reviewed, therefore I didn't see the other ones. Before posting an answer, please read carefully the question, not just the title.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the conversation but I found a better option.
In rider you can enable "open project files with single click"
Just go to the `solution options menu` and then click in `open project files with single click`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's an extension for Visual Studio named **"Edit Project"**, which can be downloaded from the Visual Studio Marketplace, [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Heku.EditProject2022).

<sub>I'm not affiliated with this extension or creator in any way. Just a happy user.</sub>