# Trouble converting a console application to a WPF application in VS 2010

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, console, port

I created a console application that I later decided would function better as a WPF application. I changed the output type to Windows Application and added what I believe are the necessary references. Unfortunately, right-clicking on the project does not allow me to add a Resource Dictionary or many other WPF types. What have I missed?

Comment: generally, I would recommend starting a new project and copy/include all project files from the console app solution

Comment: Which precise error message are you getting? Additionally, it would be better to decouple GUI and business logic. For example, you could use Martin Fowler's MVP (Model-View-Presenter) pattern, in one of its two flavors (Passive View and the other one, I don't remember the name). If you do this, you can have more than one view (Console and WPF), and use any of them

Comment: Dario, could you repost your comment as an answer? That's the route I ended up taking. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest method would be to create a new WPF application and move the code. The best method would be to push the logic into a business library so you can easily use a console application and a wpf application as the presentation technology for the business logic, because WPF is a user interface technology, not an application type.

From a geek standpoint, if you want to solve the hard way to learn, I would create a separate WPF applicationn and examine the proj file. Most likely there is some little bit in there that makes things work as WPF, as well as some missing references.

Answer (score 11):

I did convert my console application to WPF application by below steps
All you need to do is change project type guid in project file.
1. Add reference to PresentationCore assembly 
2. Add reference to PresentationFramework assembly 
3. Add reference to WindowsBase assembly 
4. Go to Project properties then on Application tab change output type to Windows Application. 
5. Create new project of WPF application and copy App.xaml and MainWindow or Anyother xaml files to your console application. 
And last thing to get Resource dictionary when you right click on project and select add 
Open your project file e.g. WpfApp.csproj on notepad And add

```
**<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>**
```

in first **PropertyGroup** element after **FileAlignment**  , it should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
<ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
<SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
<ProjectGuid>{58688A7B-82F4-4229-949A-C4249DAB43FC}</ProjectGuid>
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
<AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
<RootNamespace>ConsoleApplication1</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>ConsoleApplication1</AssemblyName>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
<StartupObject>
</StartupObject>
```

Save it. if your project is open in visual sutiod it will ask to reload project, click yes.
Thats it, it is now working as WPF Application and you will find Add all menus which are available on WPF application.

Comment: I also had to add "new app().Run(new MainWindow())" in my Program.cs to get it to start. [STAThread] was required as well.

Comment: Without ProjectTypeGUID attribute, I was manually able to add files and work. Once I added Project GUID the VS solution explorer context menu and the project template started showing the Window and other wpf types

Answer (score 6):

*I started to edit the answer from RAJ (as the steps listed there are incomplete), but my changes were a little too drastic, so I decided to post my answer separately.*

You can convert a console application to a WPF application with these steps:

1. Add reference to the following assemblies:

   - PresentationCore
   - PresentationFramework
   - WindowsBase
   - System.Xaml
2. Open Project properties. On Application tab, change output type to Windows Application.
3. Create new WPF application (e.g. name it "**tempWPF**") and copy App.xaml and MainWindow.xaml (along with the backing .xaml.cs files for both) to your console application.

   - Replace all occurences of "**tempWPF**" with the name of your console project.
4. In the Properties window for App.xaml, set *Build Action* to `ApplicationDefinition` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26441321/93394)).
5. Remove/Delete Program.cs file from the project. (After relocating any custom logic from that file as necessary, of course).
6. Change the project type guid. To do this, edit your project file (e.g. WpfApp.csproj) either in Notepad++ or [directly in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129214/93394), adding the following line somewhere in first **PropertyGroup** element:

   ```
   <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
   ```
7. Reload your project in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone else said, the practical way of making a WPF is to just start a new WPF application project and adapt your console code. However, Gregory A Beamer is correct at pointing out that you may want the geek solution.

Maybe this would be the place to look for the right option:

In the menu, hit Tools >> Customize. In the "Customize" dialog, hit the "Commands" tab, and then click on the "Editor Context Menus" radio button. You can now edit all the context menus in VS. I assume these context menus get automatically customized for each application type. The context menu used to add a resource dictionary to the project should be somewhere in here. Though changing them manually may be a pain in the behind, the geek point is that they're still there.