# program doesn't contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know that have a lot of question about this issue but my problem is worst.
I have a big project that contains a lot WPF application. In mistake I have been deleted the App.xaml, and now I have error in the building.What I try is to take the backup App.xaml and even when I put it again in my project, and I still got this error.
What to do ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you re-compile it after restoring from backup?  Is the backup valid?  Is it included in the project or just a file in the directory?  Basically, following the error message, *is there* a `static Main` method in the application?  (Side note: An effective way to undo a breaking change in the code is to revert to a known working version from source control.)

Answer (score 14):

In the file properties, set *Build Action* to `ApplicationDefinition`:

[image: file properties]

This will generate a `Main` method for you in the intermediate output files (obj/App.g.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// Application Entry Point.
/// </summary>
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
public static void Main() {
    YourAppName.App app = new YourAppName.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}
```