# Finding assembly dependencies in a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-assembly

I have a solution where one of the references is refering to google.protobuff v3.1.0.0, but when building the solution I get the older version google.protobuff v3.0.0.0.

From what I gather one of the other references in the project is refering to v3.0.0.0 and overriding v3.1.0.0, but how can I find who's referring to it? there are tons of references in the project.

I tried using Analyze Assembly Dependencies, but it shows that google.protobuff.dll is dangling (means no one depends on it).

Thank you,
Ofir

Answer (score 4):

You can check which project uses a particular assembly and which version, using the Solution Explorer.

Example - searching for the Newtonsoft.Json assembly:

[image: Solution Explorer search]

Also, if your assembly is coming from a Nuget package, right-click your solution and select "**Manage NuGet Packages for Solution**" and then "**Consolidate**" to check if there are different versions of the package/assembly in the solution:

[image: Nuget consolidate]

Comment: Is this only for VS2015?

Comment: @BurnsBA I'm using VS2017. Nuget consolidate is available from VS2015, I think. Searching files using the solution explorer should work with older versions of VS, but I'm not sure if it's possible to search for assemblies in the solution

Comment: First of, thank you for your help. I tried searching the solution for the google.protobuf assembly, no results found (and I know at least one reference is using it)... :(

Comment: @O.San which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @O.San another option is to open the project files and search for references onf the assembly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129214/558486