# Windows Forms Controls disappearing during design time

Tags: controls, windows-forms-designer

I have created a Windows Forms application using C# two join the functionalities of two other Windows Forms applications, in Visual Studio 2019. These two applications have references to some external dlls.

Now I have copy pasted the contents of the two old applications and added the dlls and other references, to the new application. But now, the UI controls are not being displayed during the design time. UI controls are perfectly displayed while running the application.

In Visual Studio 2012 the design file is showing an error, whose image is attached here. This application is for acquiring data from a Raman Spectrometer and do signal processing after that.

[image: Error in VS 2012]

Comment: Try to comment all back-end code. uncomment  small piece of code step by step. Ctrl+S all the times when you make changes. Hopes it will helps. Thanks

Comment: Looking at the files in your *Solution Explorer*, Form1 and Form1.designer aren't related hierarchically. Try hopping into your CSPROJ file as *Program.CS* seems like it is initialized correctly. Try editing the XML entries for *Form1* in the same style as *Program*.
Check out this link about the CSPROJ file for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129090/how-to-edit-csproj-file