# C# - why costura and fody doesn't work to me?

Tags: exe, fody, fody-costura

(Translator used.)
I was making an exe file using Costura and Fody. However, if the dll file is missing, it cannot run. And there is a warning in my Visual Studio.
Warn:
`FodyPackageReference Fody: The package reference for Costura.Fody is missing the 'compile' part in the IncludeAssets setting; it's recommended to completely remove IncludeAssets`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have this warn, too. But it works fine for me. So **it's not the warn that leads to your issue**.

In my opinion, maybe it's because the costura version does't fit your project. **You can try an older version.**

As for me, my project is using .NET Framework 4.6, and the latest costura.fody 5.3 version isn't compatible. But the 5.2 work fine.

**And how to remove the warn:**
(edit the csproj file)

Find below and comment "`IncludeAssets`" line as below (by adding `<!-- -->`)

```
    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Costura.Fody">
    <Version>5.2.0</Version>
    <!--<IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>-->
```

If you don't know how to edit this file you can find the steps here: [How to edit .csproj file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129214)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like previous answer, I got rid of the warning this way:

1. Double click on project node
2. In CSPROJ file add "compile;":

```
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; compile; build;.....
```

3. Reload project

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the error message tells you what to do:
"... it's recommended to completely remove IncludeAssets".

More specifically, in your project file ( .csproj or .vbprog ) find where it says as an example:

```
  <PackageReference Include="Fody">
  <Version>6.3.0</Version>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  </PackageReference>
```

and change it to:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Fody">
    <Version>6.3.0</Version>
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

(i.e. remove the <IncludeAssets .....> line entirely).

Doing this, as applicable, for both costura and fody.

Comment: have you reported this to the Fody repository? I am confused by this warning and am wondering if it is safe to do as Visual Studio advises.