# Visual studio pack NuGet without building folder

Tags: c, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have a working visual studio 2019 project with a simple nuget package, where if I right click 'ClassLibrary2' and click 'pack' it packages my project into a NuGet package

[image]

I want to package this folder NxTestware, when I include the folder in my project and try to pack again, it results in errors that come from inside the source folder, like it is trying to build the contents of that folder

[image]

Is there some way in visual studio I can tell it that when I click 'pack', do not build the contents of the NxTestware folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying I can't reproduce your issue on my side, please check your project's csproj file, and refer to this document: [How to: Exclude files from the build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-exclude-files-from-the-build?view=vs-2022).

Comment: In the link you shared there examples with xml code that i assume is inside csproj files. but where can I find this csproj ? is it created by default in visual studio? or do i have to make it manually? I cant find the csproj  in my solutions explorer

Comment: nevermind i was able to do so here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129090/how-to-edit-csproj-file trying it now

Comment: I added `<Compile Exclude="NxTestware" />` to my project file, but it causes an error `The attribute "Exclude" in element <Compile> is unrecognized.`

Comment: Try <Content Include=" YourFolder\\**\*.*"> <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory> </Content>

Comment: I got it working with ` <ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="NxTestware\**" />
  <EmbeddedResource Remove="NxTestware\**" />
  <None Remove="NxTestware\**" />
 </ItemGroup>`