# Error CS0017 "Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point." problem

Tags: c#, properties, program-entry-point, visual-studio-2022

I opened a new project right now, and I opened a new class there with a "Main" inside it.
I already read whole over the internet about it and I already got that it happens because I have more than one "Main" method, but I read that when you choose inside the - *Properties --> Startup object* - your "Main" that you want to open it should be fixed.

The problem is that it doesn't show them at all.
What am I suppose to do?

That's the Error:

> CS0017    Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.

**My classes:**

First -

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BeginnerProject
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Second -

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BeginnerProject
{
    internal class FakeCoin
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");
        }
    }
}
```

Third -

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BeginnerProject
{
    internal class WhyLikeThat
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

**Properties:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wkYV.png

Comment: Why are you determined to have 3 `Main`s in your project?  Why not just change the names?

Comment: Because that's the way I know, also I know that it suppose to have a solution so I wanna know what's wrong with what I did.

Comment: The solution is to have one `Main` in your project.  I bet you can use that `/main` arg (or something similar) to specify which project and make this work, but it's confusing and pretty pointless

Comment: But I'm going to have a lot of Classes, how am I suppose to do all that with one Main? (sorry I'm new to all this)

Comment: To do what with one Main? @yehonatan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [official documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/advanced#mainentrypoint-or-startupobject), you just need to specify your entry point in your `.csproj` by using the `<StartupObject>` or the `<MainEntryPoint>` tag.

In your case you should be writting something like `<StartupObject>BeginnerProject.FakeCoin</StartupObject>` if you want the second class to be your entry point.

Comment: Sorry for having lack of basic information, but how do I get to the `.csproj`.

Comment: You should find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129090/how-to-edit-csproj-file ;)
In Visual Studio 2022, you also have the possibility to edit your .csproj without unloading the project (right click on your project and look for `Edit [YourProject].csproj`)