Cannot see .csproj files in Visual Studio 2022 Solution Explorer
I have tried to see WPF Application .csproj files using Solution Explorer in VS 2022 and 2022 Preview and followed all the options suggested by GitHub Copilot without success.  When I look at a WPF Application through Windows File Explorer I can see the .csproj files, as below.

But when I look for them in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer they don’t appear, see below.  Even the VS Quick Find can’t locate them.

Can anyone tell me how to view them through VS 2022 Solution Explorer please?

This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129090/how-to-edit-csproj-file

Thanks, Anonymous.  A very helpful reference.  Most appreciated.

If you want to view .csproj files in Visual Studio 2022 Solution Explorer, you can click "Switch Views button" to switch between the default Solution view and the optional Folder view.
In Folder view, you can see project files.

In default Solution view, if you need to edit the .csproj file directly, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and select “Edit Project File” to open .csproj files.

Wow, wow, wow, Dou Xu.  A simple and elegant salve to my hours long pain.   Anonymous above helped also but your answer was so short and sweet.  Thank you.
