# How can I fold .cs files inside .xaml files in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, computer-science, folding

How can I put my ViewModel file (a .cs file) folded inside its corresponded View file (a .xaml file) file like in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it in visual studio, but you can edit your .csproj file in a text editor. You should find something like this:

```
<Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Page>
<Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
```

The two tags might not be right next to each other in your file. The important part is the `<DependantUpon>` tag.

In your file, find the tag with the `include="ViewModel.cs"` attribute. Inside of this tag, add `<DependantUpon>View.xaml</DependantUpon>` as a child element. Now your ViewModel.cs file will always be a inside the View.xaml file. In the end, your file should have these something similar to this snippet:

```
<Page Include="View.xaml">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
</Page>
<Compile Include="ViewModel.cs">
  <DependentUpon>View.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621345/how-to-group-partial-class-files-in-solution-explorer-vs2010 for a GUI way to do this

Comment: Still would be nice if there was a default GUI method. Seems like an obvious thing to have from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot of try and error finally I've came up with a satisfying solution. this is an old question, but I'm gonna leave this here anyway.

If you want to all of your viewmodels nested under your views e.g. `MainWindowViewModel.cs` be folded inside `MainWindow.xaml` and these lines to your csproj

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Update="**\*ViewModel.cs">
            <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy(%(Filename)).Replace('ViewModel', '.xaml'))</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
```

And then unload and reload the project. now if you add any class file that has the `ViewModel.cs` postfix in its name, it's going to be listed under your .xaml file.