# why my file xaml and file cs are separated

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

In my shared project My.cs file is no longer dependent on my .Xaml file. In the explorer they appear next to each other instead of file.cs appearing only when I click on are parent file.Xaml

i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131526/how-can-i-fold-cs-files-inside-xaml-files-in-visual-studio-2010)

but is too old

Comment: That answer is answering your question as well unload the project and Edit the CsProj then do as it says

Comment: Your question is really unclear, I understand it just because I guessed what you mean.

Comment: Have you checked the **folder**, or are you talking about the **Solution Explorer**?

Answer (score 3):

I have run into this issue a number of times.

Fastest solution for this problem is to - rename your .xaml file and rename it back to the original allowing it to combine back with itself.

This works every single time 100%. I have been very annoyed multiple times because of this and this is the fastest solution I've found.

I'm also extremely surprised this bug exists in 2023 and isn't fixed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after 6 hours i found a stupid things of newbies 
this architecture is created by the choice standard.net

But is it a bug ?
I would to make a shared project because the standard.net dosnt work with firebase

[file xaml separeted of cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVZ0h.png)

Comment: that was a bug to fix add Universal Windows Platform tools