# Creating sub items in solution explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We use allot of partial classes in C# to categorise our code for large classes. In the solution explorer we will have code files listed as such:

```
- MyClass.cs
- MyClass.Partial1.cs
- MyClass.Partial2.cs
```

But what we want to have is something like this (as you would see with designer files etc.):

```
- MyClass.cs
    ˪ MyClass.Partial1.cs
    ˪ MyClass.Partial2.cs
```

I'm aware that you can modify the project file manually to set-up this dependency like this:

```
<Compile Include="MyClass.cs" />
<Compile Include="MyClass.Partial1.cs">
    <DependentUpon>MyClass.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="MyClass.Partial2.cs">
    <DependentUpon>MyClass.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Is there a short-cut in visual studio? Or maybe an extension that will help with this? (Without needing to edit the project file manually)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621345/how-to-group-partial-class-files-in-solution-explorer-vs2010) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617539/group-files-in-visual-studio) question.

Their answer: `Group Items` as available in [VSCommands for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf/)

There is also a plugin that does **only** this: [NestIn](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9d6ef0ce-2bef-4a82-9a84-7718caa5bb45)

**Update**
There is a second plugin that does pretty much the same thing: [File Nesting](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ebde8fb-26d8-4374-a0eb-1e4e2665070c)

Comment: Thanks. There is also a new version for [VS2012](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/features)