# Handling filetypes that contain multiple files?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, resx, file-type

Some filetypes in Visual Studio includes more then one file, for example resx and winform files. So If I need to add existing filetyp of this type I always end upp with multiple files in solution explorer? Are thay not supose to be shown as one file based on there name?

BestRegards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So If I need to add existing filetyp of this type I always end upp
>   with multiple files in solution explorer?
>   Multiple file is the part of ProjectItem template. If you add WinFor you will always get several files.

If you don't want to use such template you can create your own template from code created ones with **File->Export Template** wizard.

To group files in solution explorer read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621345/how-to-group-partial-class-files-in-solution-explorer-vs2010)

Comment: Not clear on your suggestion. What Im saying is that if you create a winform the winform will infact consist of a 2 cs files and a resx file. In Visual Studio solution explorer will show it like 1 file with subfiles. If I import these 3 files in to another project it is not always handled by the solution explorer as 1 file with subfiles but 3 induvidual files. And this is my problem with resx files as well.

Comment: I've add the link to another thread. Look throught it to understand the item grouping method. You can remove <DependentUpon> tag to undo subitems in solution explorer.