# How to create a class that will be under of a class in solution explorer?

Tags: c#, class, solution-explorer

First I created a class file named `Bootstrap.cs`, then I created another class name `Bootstrap.Designer.cs`, the awesome part is `Bootstrap.Designer.cs` become under of first class.

[image: Bootstrap.Designer.cs]

So I decide to create another class called `Bootstrap.Sample.cs`

[image]

But the problem here is the third class not become under of first class.

Is there any list of class naming exist like `*.Designer.cs` that allowed to be under of first class?

Comment: If I had to guess; Designer gets special treatment because of its association with Windows Forms

Comment: Why not look in the .csproj file and see what's special about Bootstrap.Designer.cs?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET So there is no other way to make another class like Designer?

Comment: the `.csproj` file is just an xml file. Open it up with your favorite text editor and take a look!

Comment: @JohnSaunders I created it in console. where is `.csproj`?

Comment: Also, those are the file names, not class names.

Comment: The csproj file is in your solution folder (in Windows Explorer) you have to open it outside of VS.

Comment: the .csproj is (likely) in the same directory as your other files

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You can open it inside VS if you unload the project first.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault ah; excellent point. I had forgotten about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using VSCommands plugin for Visual Studio. Simply highlight the two files, right click in Solution Explorer, and choose group.

If you want to do it manually you can right click on your project file in solution explorer, choose Unload Project. Then you can right click and edit the project, which will allow you to see the underlying XML. You're looking for

```
<Compile Include="yourfilename.cs" />
```

which you will need to change to

```
<Compile Include="yourfilename.cs">
   <DependentUpon>parentFile.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

This is described in [How to group partial class files in Solution Explorer VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621345/how-to-group-partial-class-files-in-solution-explorer-vs2010)

Answer (score 2):

There's a file nesting extension in the Visual Studio gallery that allows you to nest/un-nest files in Solution Explorer. It also lets you set up naming rules so files that conform to certain naming conventions will automatically be nested.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ebde8fb-26d8-4374-a0eb-1e4e2665070c

Comment: Awesome Tool! This is really useful in `vs2013'.