# Partial Classes in WinForms

Tags: c#, multithreading

Iam having a trouble when integrating this exteremly brilliant solution [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694062/can-a-tcp-c-sharp-client-receive-and-send-continuously-consecutively-without-sle) in my winform application that will read/write data at the same time  . I have compiling errors : 
First : Error CS0262    Partial declarations of 'Client' have conflicting accessibility modifiers
Second : Error  CS0535  'Client' does not implement interface member 'IDisposable.Dispose()'
in this part of code which is red-highlited :

```
 public sealed partial class Client : IDisposable
```

Comment: all your partial classes with same name (which together become single class) need to have same access modifiers. for example all have to be `public` or all have to be `internal`

Comment: Restore the original.  Right-click the identifier > Refactor > Rename.

Comment: may i  ask another question please : in the file Client.Sender.cs , internal void SendData ,"transition the data to the thread and send it" ,   how is it possible to transition the data to the thread (private void run()) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is because your `Client` class has `Partial` classes where the accessibility is different. e.g. you would get the same error if you had the following:

```
public partial class MyClassName
{
    //rest of code
}
```

and

```
protected partial class MyClassName
{
    //rest of code
}
```

where the classes are in the same namespace. They should either be both `public` or both `protected`.

Answer (score 1):

1 . In Client.Receiver.cs and Client.Sender.cs change class to public

```
public sealed partial class Client
```

2. remove  `: IDisposable`