# Send out message from server to all clients c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I try to create a server program in console with C#. I use ThreadPool to create separate socket for each clients. Then, I create a `static List<TcpClient> clients = new List<TcpClient>();`to contains all clients connected to.

Then, what I want is, when 1 client send to server a message, server will receive and send it out to all client connected. So, I wrote:

```
foreach (var item in clients)
{
   ns.Write(data, 0, recv);
   //send message to all client
}
```

But, only client just sent the message can receive it back, another clients was receive nothing!

**** Server side:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
class ThreadedTcpSrvr
{
    private TcpListener client;

    //private 

    public ThreadedTcpSrvr()
    {
        client = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9050);
        client.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for clients...");
        while (true)
        {
            while (!client.Pending())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            ConnectionThread newconnection = new ConnectionThread();
            newconnection.threadListener = this.client;
            Thread newthread = new Thread(new
                 ThreadStart(newconnection.HandleConnection));
            newthread.Start();
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        ThreadedTcpSrvr server = new ThreadedTcpSrvr();
    }
}
class ConnectionThread
{
    static List<TcpClient> clients = new List<TcpClient>();
    public TcpListener threadListener;
    private static int connections = 0;
    public void HandleConnection()
    {
        int recv;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        TcpClient client = threadListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
        //TcpClient clientSocket = client.AccepTcpClient();
        clients.Add(client);
        connections++;
        Console.WriteLine("New client accepted: {0} active connections",
                 connections);
        string welcome = "Welcome to my test server";
        data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
        ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        while (true)
        {
            data = new byte[1024];
            recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            if (recv == 0)
                break;
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));
            //ns.Write(data, 0, recv);
            foreach (var item in clients)
            {
                ns.Write(data, 0, recv);
                //send message to client
            }
        }
        ns.Close();
        client.Close();
        connections--;
        Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected: {0} active connections",connections);
    }
}
```

**** Client side:

```
void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult iar)
{
   try
   {
       while(true)
       {
          Socket remote = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
          int recv = remote.EndReceive(iar);
          string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
          ListAddItem(stringData);
       }
   }
   catch
   {

   }
```

}

Comment: because of ns.write in your clients loop - you arent using the socket for each client but the one you received with.  Which you were hinted at when you asked basically the same question earlier

Comment: do a `item.Write(data, 0, recv);` instead in the for loop.

Comment: @FrankNielsen, you mean `item.GetStream().Write(..)`

Comment: can't use item.Write(data, 0, recv); because TcpClient does not contain Write() method.

Comment: In general, thread-per-socket doesn't scale well. You're better off using some form of async (there are a number of options for sockets) and letting windows lend you I/O threads on those small occasions when *there's something useful for a thread to do*, such as to process a buffer full of data that has (finally!) arrived over the network.

Comment: Others have pointed out the typo in your code. For future reference, here's something you can be on the lookout for: if you have a `for` or `foreach` loop and in the loop you **never use the loop variable**, you've probably done something wrong. This is especially true for `foreach` loops. As for your basic approach, I also agree that you should learn the async APIs so you can avoid dedicating a whole thread to each client. FWIW, you can see a detailed chat example I posted recently, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44942011

Answer (score 0):

Your ns (network stream is on a per client basis )

In the following code your ns is for the incoming client. So you are iterating over all clients but then only talking to the client that is currently incoming

```
        foreach (var item in clients)
        {
            ns.Write(data, 0, recv);
            //send message to client
        }
```

Agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is will work for a small number of clients but when you start to scale over 2000+ clients you will run into performance problems. With the thread switching and the amount of ports that need to be opened. It would be better to use an event / async based architecture