# Send Continuously Data Through the Socket C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I've searched over 2 weeks for samples or anything else for my question.
Found some topics and examples but can't use them ...
Here is the problem : I have a server-client application which the server have to listen all the time and client is sending continuously Images to the server. 
I've done the send-and-done which means client send 1 image to the server and server receive the image and socket will be closed . 
But i want to send continuously Images to the server ...  
Found this question :   [Can a TCP c# client receive and send continuously/consecutively without sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694062/can-a-tcp-c-sharp-client-receive-and-send-continuously-consecutively-without-sle?answertab=active#tab-top)  
But can't use them and samples . 
I know the basic TCP Socket Programming and Basics of Thread Programming , but can't implement this . 
Sorry For my bad english ! 
=====edit 
actually a timer captured a screenshot with 1 second interval and these captured images after a process for compressing are send to server . 
its continuously sending (Just Sending). 
Is there any sample or something that i can use ? 
Thanks .

Comment: " server receive the image and socket will be closed . " why is the socket closed? do you have control over the server code? Furthermore, we cannot help you really if you don't provide the important code that you have wrote

Comment: You have told us what you **cannot** do. You have not told us *why* or *what's the problem*. There is no question we could answer.

Answer (score 2):

When sending a single message on a socket, you can just send the payload and close - and the receiver just has to read until the socket reports it has closed and they'll have the message; nice and simple, but it doesn't scale to multiple messages.

You can't just use the packet layout because TCP is implemented as a *stream* protocol not a *packet* protocol; how you receive the data does not need to match (in terms of packets) how it is sent.

Thus, to send multiple messages on a TCP socket you need to implement some kind of *framing* mechanism. Any number of framing mechanism are available. A very simple mechanism might be to send a sequence of:

- length (4 bytes, little-endian 32-bit integer)
- payload ({length} bytes)
- length (4 bytes, little-endian 32-bit integer)
- payload ({length} bytes)
- length (4 bytes, little-endian 32-bit integer)
- payload ({length} bytes)
- length (4 bytes, little-endian 32-bit integer)
- payload ({length} bytes)

And similarly the recipient would buffer 4 bytes, interpret the length, then read *that many* bytes as a frame; rinse, repeat.