# Xamarin/WinForms clients unable to connect to a socket when sending/receiving in a two threaded architecture

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, sockets, xamarin.forms

### Goal

Send and receive message from TCP socket on **two different threads** in a UI program.

### Problem

I can't connect to a socket and send/receive data **ONLY when** I'm in Xamarin.Forms and WinForms. So this is some kind of a threading issue.

When I try connecting it just times out [here](https://github.com/sturlath/TcpClientSendReceive/blob/a15c936889412e5a4ac249df2b291db817d40307/TcpClientLib/Client.cs#L70) so there is no error or nothing.

### What I have been trying

I have been working heavily with [Matt Davis solution here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694062/can-a-tcp-c-sharp-client-receive-and-send-continuously-consecutively-without-sle/20698153#20698153).

I created a **[test code](https://github.com/sturlath/TcpClientSendReceive)** (*TcpClientSendReceive*) at GitHub with all the code needed.

### My code

Its all on GitHub in [this repository](https://github.com/sturlath/TcpClientSendReceive). I cant fit it all in here. But here is the [connection code](https://github.com/sturlath/TcpClientSendReceive/blob/a15c936889412e5a4ac249df2b291db817d40307/TcpClientLib/Client.cs#L84) that does not seem to work with e.g Xamarin.Forms [see that code here](https://github.com/sturlath/TcpClientSendReceive/blob/a15c936889412e5a4ac249df2b291db817d40307/XamarinForms/TcpClientMobileApp/Views/ItemsPage.xaml.cs#L28).

If I try to [connect](https://github.com/sturlath/TcpClientSendReceive/blob/a15c936889412e5a4ac249df2b291db817d40307/TcpClientLib/Client.cs#L84) to my console server from a UI I can't connect (witch means that I can´t either send/receive)

### Does the baseline code work?

Yes it does. At least when I run the two Client/Server programs it sends data between each other.

### What could be the problem?

Definitely how threading is setup and how it interacts with the UI. I'm just lacking enough threading experience to be able to figure this out. I hope some of you do! :-)

**EDIT:**

### BOUNTY INFORMATION

I created a more [detailed bounty information page on GitHub](https://github.com/sturlath/TcpClientSendReceive/issues/3) so it would be totally clear what I needed.

I added **LOTS** of images and links to code. It should be very easy to get the code and just try it out. **Please try it out**. I really don´t think this is a big issue for somebody lower level than me.

Comment: Can you describe the error etc. "I can't connect" could mean a loada things!

Comment: Yes sorry. I updated the question. It just times out. That's why I added the timeout part. I have tried all kinds of versions of this code. But it works with the server/client console apps but just not with the UI apps.

Comment: What if one side is console and the other is xamarin?

Comment: @noelicus that is my main problem and setup that doesn't seem to work. I run up the Android emulator and then the ServiceConsole. Take a look at the details in [this issue](https://github.com/sturlath/TcpClientSendReceive/issues/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this?

```
public class HandleClient
    {
        private TcpClient clientSocket;
        private static int bufferLength = 1024;
        private byte[] readBuffer = new byte[bufferLength];

        public void StartClient(TcpClient inClientSocket)
        {
            this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;

            var ctThread = new Thread(Chat);
            ctThread.Start();
        }

        private void Chat()
        {
            var reader = clientSocket.GetStream();

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var bytesRead = reader.Read(readBuffer, 0, bufferLength);

                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        memoryStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        var message = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

                        Log.Debug("Server got this message from client: {message}", message);

                        foreach (TcpClient client in Program.GetClients())
                        {
                            var writer = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());
                            writer.Write($"Server got your message '{message}'");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (EndOfStreamException)
            {
                Log.Error($"client disconnecting: {clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint}");
                clientSocket.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.Error($"IOException reading from {clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint}: {e.Message}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
            {
                Log.Error(e, "Error (ObjectDisposedException) receiving from server");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error(e, "Error receiving from server");
            }

            clientSocket.Close();
            Program.RemoveClient(clientSocket);
            Log.Debug("{count} clients connected", Program.GetClientCount());
        }
    }
```

[image: Winform]

[image: android]

[image: communication]

if your winform can not receive message.
you must change OnClient_MainDataReceived method to

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                txbResponseFromServer.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                txbResponseFromServer.AppendText(e.Data);
            });
```

Comment: This looks promising. Do you mind doing a PR on GitHub with the full implementation so I can try it out?

Comment: i changed just your HandleClient.

i checked packet with wireshark.
now your client application sent packet.
but your binaryreader can not receive packet.

i don't know why....
i found many website. but i couldn't find.
so i changed your listener.

my english is so bad.
so this explain is my limit....

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you so much! Now the Service at least receives the data that the Client sends so the problem has become why the client isn't receiving the response from the Service. We are half way there! p.s I updated the GitHub code with your code thanks.

Comment: your client can not get receive message?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clients and a server communicate inconsistently. Server uses `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` and clients write/read bytes to a "raw" stream as is. The difference is that `BinaryWriter` writes not only `string` bytes but also its length bytes before the `string` itself and `BinaryReader` doesn't read all currently available bytes from network and converts them to a `string` but it reads the length first and then hanldes reading the exact amount of byte needed to get a full `string`.

So the easiest would be using `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` everywhere since they hanlde reading complex data (`string`) bytes, encoding and decoding them for you.

Although implementing you own communication protocol and working directly with `NetworkStream` methods for reading/writing bytes gives you more flexibility it requires an extra effort to make it work correctly. For example there is a single method for reading multiple bytes from network

```
int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
```

When server sends a `string` client doesn't know how many bytes it should read. It can create large buffer that can hold some reasonable amount of bytes. But if server sends two strings one by one client could read them both into a buffer at once and data could be possibly corrupted already. At this point you need to implement your communication protocol for sending complete messages via network. Another caveat for the `Read` method is that it may read not all currently available data from network at once and `size` value doesn't guarantee amount of read bytes. For example you know that server sends client `n` bytes and client reads them

```
stream.Read(buffer, 0, n)
```

Is is possible that client will read only some part of that bytes in one `Read` call and the remaining part will still be on network stream available to be read. You should consider that and handle this situation by reading bytes in a loop while need amount has been read.

Comment: I created pull request for this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but I believe I see the deadlock in this method:
https://github.com/sturlath/TcpClientSendReceive/blob/a15c936889412e5a4ac249df2b291db817d40307/TcpClientLib/Client.cs#L37

This might be enough to fix it:

```
await Task.Run(() => _client.GetStream()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Looks like the client & server are trying to connect in the ui synchronization context. That's a single thread so it's not going to work. If it still locks up you may have some other places that need to be fixed as well.