# Group files in Webstorm / IntelllijIDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Is it possible to group related items in Webstorm same way as in Visual Studio ([Group files in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617539/group-files-in-visual-studio))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only be done for files generated by File watchers. there are no means to group arbitrary files, please feel free to vote for [IDEABKL-6196](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6196). Related ticket: [WEB-7635](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7635)

Answer (score 2):

Since Webstorm 2016.3, file nesting will be done automatically based on hardcoded rules (listed [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21873#comment=27-1515879))

There is an issue about making these rules configurable ([WEB-17977](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17977))

**UPDATE:**

Since version 2017.2 all JetBrains IDE's support custom rule-based file nesting: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17977#comment=27-2197872