# How to hide js and js.map file in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a Angular 2 project in Visual Studio 2015.  Is there a way to hide the js and js.map files in Visual Studio 2015 like in VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have included js and js.map files in the project, you can group those items together and have the ts file display as the root.

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617539/group-files-in-visual-studio). There are also extensions such as VSCommands that can do this for you using context menu.