# How to write c# partial interfaces like this

Tags: c#

I just started to follow this git hub repo https://github.com/hassanhabib/OtripleS for my learning stuff.

here I see this kind of sub interfaces under this `IStorageBroker` interface.

[image]

`IStorageBroker` interface like this

```
public partial interface IStorageBroker
{
}
```

and `IStorageBroker.Assignments`

```
public partial interface IStorageBroker
{
    ValueTask<Assignment> InsertAssignmentAsync(Assignment assignment);
    IQueryable<Assignment> SelectAllAssignments();
    ValueTask<Assignment> SelectAssignmentByIdAsync(Guid assignmentId);
    ValueTask<Assignment> UpdateAssignmentAsync(Assignment assignment);
    ValueTask<Assignment> DeleteAssignmentAsync(Assignment assignment);
}
```

I'm wondering how to create interfaces like this, means when expanding top interface there are several sub interfaces. how to create those like that in visual studio? Is this something related to [c# partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods)?

Comment: Its just a way to organize the physical code files on disk. The compiled interface will be the same, it is not actually split into multiple sub-interfaces.

Comment: This is a question about partial interfaces rather than partial classes. There are somewhat different considerations.

Comment: @lgor how can I create new interface? i just create interface by write click on the solution explorer and name it as IStorageBroker.Test. but it's not coming up under IStorageBroker

Comment: If you actually want "subinterfaces", define them individually and then have the master interface inherit from them all.

Answer (score 2):

A major purpose of partial classes is to separate code that a code generator creates from code that a programmer adds to the generated code. That's not the only way to use them, but that's their original reason for existence.

C# allows the creation of partial interfaces, but I have never found that feature useful. If you need an interface that can logically be composed of two other interfaces that separately serve a useful purpose in your type model, you can use inheritance to model that relationship:

```
interface IFoo 
{
    public int A();
}

interface IBar
{
    public int B();
}

interface IBaz : IFoo, IBar
{
    
}

class Quuz : IBaz
{
    public int A()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int B()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If a class should satisfy two interface contracts that are not naturally related, the class can implement both interfaces without the need to create any sort of relationship between them in your code.

```
class Quack : IFoo, IBar
{
    public int A()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int B()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The language does *allow* you to declare partial interfaces, which simply separates the definition of a single interface across multiple files. I have never had occasion to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much, but i'm wondering why visual studio showing IStorageBroker.AssignmentAttachments ,IStorageBroker.Assignments like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVREd.png )  when click IStorageBroker like hierarchy.? if i need to add another one (ex IStorageBroker .Test ) under IStorageBroker  how can I do it?

Comment: This is typically done via csproj and DependentUpon attribute in the element referencing the file. Since it is not possible to discern the project from your screenshot, it is hard to tell exactly how it is done in this case. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3617539/3593970